# Check which button was selected on previous page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an initial landing page which has 2 submit buttons on it. One button will display a specific set of results and the other button will display a different set.

Basically I am passing through the text value onto the next page for it to display some player biographys and reviews.

```
<form action="resultpage.html" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="playerName" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

I was wondering is it possible when I hit button 1 it will display my biography function information and only it, then when I hit button 2 it will display only the blogreviews functions' information.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        biography(files);
        blogsreviews(files);
});
```

Comment: As a side note, you do not delete questions that you post especially after they have been answered and you could have accepted it. You just deleted one a moment ago you posted (on 3/10/2015)

Answer (score 1):

You can name the buttons and have jquery call the specific function on button click:

```
<form action="resultpage.html" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="playerName" />
    <input type="submit" name="button1" value="Submit"/>
    <input type="submit" name="button2" value="Submit"/>
</form>

$(document).ready(function() {
        $('input[name="button1"]').click(function() {biography(files)});
        $('input[name="button2"]').click(function() {blogsreviews(files)});
});
```